# Как проверить соответсвие запроса от joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Как проверить, что на сервер пришел запрос от конкретной `joomla`, например, если запрос от `joomla1` то выполнить код1, если нет - что-то другое?

Comment: Что значит "от конкретной joomla" ?  Куда приходит запрос ?